# rewriting http requests on proxy python

Tags: python, linux, proxy

i need some suggestions on performance tuning this script which reads URL headers dumped by the proxy on a temporary ram disk, it reads the file and appends it to a list, after some checks it reads the List and if the line contains "User-Agent" redits and is flushed out using standard output...

```
proc = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
    slog.write("writing standard input \n")
    for line in proc.readlines():
        header.append(line)

      . . . . . . . . 

        if check_header == None: #check_header is returned by one of the functions to whether rewrite the header
            for h in header:
                if "User-Agent" in h and "custom-header:" not in h:
                    h = h.rstrip("\r\n") + " custom-header:" + customer + "\r\n"
                sys.stdout.write(h)
                sys.stdout.flush()
            #sys.exit(1)

        else:
            sys.stdout.write(new_get)
```

my concern is that for large amount of requests its going to be slow, as it appending to list, reading it and flushing it out,  any ideas how i can performance tune it

Comment: There is no reason to use `.readlines()` here. You can iterate over a `file` object. Also, why are you iterating over the header every time you append a new element to it?

Comment: thats because i am inserting custom header to the user-agent on all requests

Answer (score 0):

Unless your indentation in the code sample is wrong, you are attempting to add the custom header as many times, as many elements you have in the list. Try

```
proc = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
slog.write("writing standard input \n")
for h in proc.readlines():

  . . . . . . . . 

    if check_header == None: #check_header is returned by one of the functions to whether rewrite the header
        if "User-Agent" in h and "custom-header:" not in h:
            h = h.rstrip("\r\n") + " custom-header:" + customer + "\r\n"
        sys.stdout.write(h)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    else:
        sys.stdout.write(new_get)
```

Comment: thanks lliyan, that does help as i am not using the list anymore, but dont think that will improve any performance...